# MediaPlayer.create doesn't read the URI

Tags: android, kotlin, android-mediaplayer

I have a following error and I'm unable to solve the problem since the URI is clearly not null. Also,  I tried to use a wave file to play the sound but it doesn't work.

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: MediaPlayer.create(appli…ionContext, R.raw.scream) must not be null
```

The code is very simple.
↓

```
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(applicationContext, R.raw.scream)


        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener {
            finish()
        }
        mediaPlayer.start()
```

I also tried to use my Uri but it's not working. I would love to hear tips or examples from you! Just to let you know I have the raw folder in the res folder. The sound file I'm using is called scream.wav

```
soundUri = Uri.parse(
            ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE +
                    File.pathSeparator +
                    File.separator +
                    File.separator +
                    packageName + "/raw/scream")
```

Comment: Is the context null?

Comment: Please tell the value of soundUri.toString().